# Creating an OS Design with a third party BSP in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

For a small project that I'm working on I need to create a Windows Embedded application. I have an Evaluation Kit with a Tegra 2 Processor from Toradex. My problem lies in setting up my environment so that I can start developing.

I am a newcomer to the whole embedded development, so please be patient.

Our Evaluation Kit is running on a beta of Windows Embedded Compact 7. As far as I read I'd need to create an OS Design in Visual Studio 2008 and then add a subproject for the application.

Toradex provides a BSP that should be used to create the OS Design. According to their instructions I can just drop the BSP in the folder where the default ones are and then the Platforn Builder should see it.
I've done this, and it doesn't work. The Platform builder won't let me choose the custom BSP.

It works when I use "Clone BSP" from the menu. But the wizzard to create a new OS Design can't find it.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers, 
Chnoch

Comment: Do you need to create a new OS image, or just an application to run on an existing one?

Comment: I just need to create an application to run on one that already exists. But so far all the tutorials I read mentioned that I need to create a Subproject in the Platform Builder. If that's not necessary it would be great if you could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating an application, you don't need a BSP.  In fact you don't even need Platform Builder.  What you need depends on the project type.

For a native (C/C++) app, you will need an SDK.  You can create one by creating a simple OS image using any of the built-in BSPs that target your same processor architecture.  Create an OS using the wizard - just pick something like a kiosk type device or whatever - build it and then generate an SDK (unfortunately you have to sysgen before you can create an SDK).

Install the SDK on any PC with Studio 2005 Standard or better or Studio 2008 Pro or better.

Create a new Smart Device Application in Studio and follow the Wizard to create an app/dll etc.

For managed (C#/VB.NET) it's even easier.  Just create a new Smart Device Application in Studio and select "Windows CE" as the target.  No SDK necessary.